# How to prove a function from $\mathbb{Q}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ to be valid.

Tags: functions

Have two questions based on mapping of functions:

> 1. Suppose define a function from $\mathbb{Q}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ to be $f(\frac{a}{b}) = 2^a3^b$, where $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ iff $(a,b)=1$.

How to prove it is a valid function, i.e. (I think) no two elements of the range get mapped by a single element of the domain.

> 2. Let there be a set of values, denoted by $S = \{2^m3^n : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$. Prove that the function $g: S \to \mathbb{Q}^+$ defined by $g(2^m3^n) = \frac{m}{n}$ is a valid function. Also, state on what properties of integers is the validity of the function based upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid function is one where each input has exactly one output. For the first question, each positive rational number has exactly one representation $\frac ab$ where $(a,b)=1$, and this representation is mapped to exactly one output. Namely, $2^a3^b$

Similarly for the second question, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, any positive integer having a form $2^m3^n$ cannot be represented by a different $2^{m'}3^{n'}$. And the representation $2^m3^n$ is mapped to exactly one output: $\frac mn$

Comment: So, the property of integers is that of primes being not divisible by any other integer except $1$.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic simply states that each positive integer has a unique prime factorization. $2^m3^n$ is a prime factorization, so it is unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for stating the importance of the FTA. Also, just a small extra statement for your vetting- the first question needs co-primes as there has to be a proper fraction, while the second one needs primes in the product.

Comment: Yes, the first question needs a proper fraction, but every (positive) fraction can be reduced to a proper fraction. The second function's domain is all integers of the form $2^m3^n$, which is more specific than just a product of primes.

Comment: Please elaborate the meaning of : "more specific than just a product of primes". I guess that you meant : it is a unique value and in the given context a need, i.e. a unique domain element's (as per the 2nd question) representation. But, will it also concern the range element of $\frac{m}{n}$, which is also unique, hence it can be additionally stated as a bijective map. Also, it makes no difference if the range elements are given by : $\frac{n}{m}$, as still a proper fraction 'can' be formed by eliminating common factors.

Comment: What I meant is just that a number such as $2*5^2$ is not in the domain of $g$. And which function are you saying is a bijective map, $f$ or $g$?

Comment: Although, I meant the function $g$ as per the second question, but both functions $f,g$ should be bijective maps.

Comment: $f$ is not bijective because it is not surjective: The codomain of $f$ is stated to be $\mathbb{Z}^+$ but the range of $f$ is just $S$. $g$ however, is bijective.

Comment: Thanks for making that differentiation to be clear. But, one last hitch regarding the rigorous proof of bijectivity of map provided by function $g$. Should I refer some literature ( like, I read much earlier by Papadimitrou on TOC, by drawing diagrams) or a simpler (and may be even more logical) proof can be thought of.

Comment: You can prove that $g$ is bijective very easily by yourself. Simply prove that it is injective and surjective. I can add this proof to my answer if you want

Comment: Yes, please. I would be thankful as yours would be a benchmark too for me to compare my efforts.

Comment: Actually, it appears I have made a mistake. $g$ is not injective because there are two distinct elements $2*3$ and $2^23^2$ which map to the same element $1$.

Comment: Yes, it is not the primes but the powers thereof. But, how can we show that fact - even to think of (imagine, as I do by a diagrammatic approach as in the text of Papadimitrou's book on TOC) is difficult.

Comment: I was waiting for your answer, and thought to make own, but very fearful as never did except by a diagrammatic approach before. In fact, never was told to provide one, it was all a part of implicit understanding.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't update my answer because I was mistaken to think that $g$ was bijective. So it's all good.

Comment: So, you mean that there is no need for a proof.

Comment: I mean that you can't prove $g$ is bijective because $g$ is not bijective.

Comment: Can there be a proof for that, or just a failure case is okay, as two or infinitely more elements of the domain map to the same element of the range. If so, then it is still a diagrammatic approach!

Comment: Like I said earlier, $6$ and $36$ both map to $1$ so $g$ is not bijective.

Comment: Thanks for stating that a failure case is okay, and this can be coupled to my formal logic that : infinitely many numbers in the domain can map to single element of the range. But, a formal proof would have guided me better. My intuition is that it boils down to : logic (as argument given by me, that in turn would need a particular example(s), as given by you) + set theoretic proof using suitable notations + a diagrammatic sort of answer; to be a rigorous proof.

Comment: @jiten  All powers of $6$ map to $1$ so you are correct that infinitely many elements of the domain map to the same element in the range.

Comment: Can I attempt a proof, on the above stated lines of my earlier comment, (of the failure of bijectivity of $g$, or better still of proving only the injectivity of function map $g$) for your vetting. I feel this would give me a lot of confidence.

Comment: @jiten But $g$ is not injective. It is surjective. And this comment section is getting very long. You might want to post your proof for verification as a separate question.

Comment: Going by the logic of function $g$, the map $f$ is not a function even, as multiple values in the range can be mapped by a single domain element.  Please correct me if I am wrong, as I see $f$ and $g$ as inverse functions. But as in $g$, there can be infinitely many domain elements mapping to a single range element, so the inverse means that a single domain element mapping to an infinite number of range elements. Hence, $f$ is not a function anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I think I am wrong; but it is confusing that it is not true. So, they are not inverse functions. Please explain the reason for this dichotomy. The dichtomy is in $g$ there are multiple numbers (unique) that map to a single range element, but in map $f$ there are "not" multiple range elements - as there is only one mapping in the range. So, if the function $f$ is from $\mathbb{Q}^+ \to S$ instead, then $f$ is a bijective mapping.

Comment: Look at $g$: $g(6)=1/1=1$ and $g(36)=2/2=1$. Let's see why this doesn't make a counterexample for $f$ being a function: $f(1/1)=6$ but $f(2/2)$ isn't defined because the input must be a reduced fraction. After reducing it to $1/1$ we see there is no contradiction here.